# Instance Group : Exceeded limit 'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES' on resource 'us-instance-group-1'. Limit: 8.0

Tags: google-compute-engine, instance, load-balancing, quota, google-cloud-cdn

I am using GCE on Asia-Southeast-b with 2vCPU 10GM for my website
I am trying to test CDN and LB, so was halfway to create an instance group in the US but it threw me an error no matter how.

Instance Group : Exceeded limit 'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES' on resource 'us-instance-group-1'. Limit: 8.0

https://prnt.sc/tzyyrk

This document from https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas leads me to think it could be due to the zone that I choose, so I have tried to choose all multi zones in different regions and even single zone but didn't allow me to create one no matter how I select it seems (I can't say I tried all different combinations but almost all).

I chose the Instance template with the lowest spec N1-standard with CentOS7 + 20G standard disk.

Under this project, I have the 4 following service accounts associated with this.

Compute Engine default service account, Google APIs Service Agent, Compute Engine Service Agent, Myself as Owner

I went to IAM & Admin > Quotas > All green checked

1. Is it because I am building this with free 300 credit?
2. How do I check which zone available I should create the instance group on?
3. What could be the reason? What did I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What is the max & min number of instances you're attempting to set in your instance group? Do you have already running instances out of the instance group?

Comment: Yes I have 1 running instance for my website and this is the 2nd instance (not even instance but instance group) I am trying to create under this project. 

In the multiple zone, I tried 3 regions checked, 2, 1, and then unchecked multiple zone and switch to single zone..

however combination, it throws me the same message... Exceeded limit.... I don't quite get it.. That's why...

Comment: Maybe this might give you better picture. https://prnt.sc/tzyyrk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be the configuration you're setting in the `Maximum number of instances`.

For example, when you create an **Instance Group**, you set the `Minimum number of instances` and the `Maximum number of instances`. Even if you set as minimum 1 instance and you left the default value for `Maximum number of instances` (which is 10), it will always fail since it checks the pre-condition that the `Maximum number of instances` never exceeds the Quota for a region.

I reproduced this by setting `Maximum number of instances` to a value greater than my quota limit.

I suggest to change the value of `Maximum number of instances` to 3 and check if you can deploy the instance group.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about this! I will have to set the "Maximum number of instances", the default is 10 which was the root cause to fail to create. I changed to 3, it successfully created the instance group! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the issue is still going on I think it might be region issue, I have set it up to max 20, and the most I still can go is 8 instances.

I suggest recreating another project and using the previous project's custom image in your new project